# Calling an AlpineJS function defined in a bundle from javascript

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have this in my bundle

```js
Alpine.store('modal', {
    open: false,
    id: null,
    close() {
        this.open = false
        this.id = false
    }
})
```

and in my blade file I have

```js
<script>
function example() {
  return {
    // some things here, and then:
    Alpine.store('modal', { open: false }) // This works
    Alpine.store('modal', { close() }) // This doesn't

  }
}
</script>
```

How do I call `close()` in my function?

Answer (score 2):

As is tradition, I found the answer 4 minutes after posting the question.

It is `Alpine.store('modal').close()`